# pandas-highchartが実行できません

Tags: python, highcharts

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas_highcharts
from pandas_highcharts.display import display_charts
```

と記述して実行すると、

> File "C:\Users\sugitomo1\Desktop\python\fx_practice2.py", line 5, in 
>       from pandas_highcharts.display import display_charts
>     File "C:\Users\sugitomo1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\b\site-packages\pandas_highcharts\display.py", line 32, in 
>   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'config'

というエラーが出てしまいます。

どのようにすればhighchartを表示できるのでしょうか？
分かる方いらっしゃいましたら、ご教授願います。。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`from pandas_highcharts.display import display_charts` でエラーが出ていますが、これはJupyter Notebookでチャートを表示するためのモジュールです<sup>1</sup>。これを使って表示するためにはJupyter Notebook上で実行する必要があります。

<sup>1 [`pandas_highcharts.display`](https://github.com/gtnx/pandas-highcharts/blob/aebcab40b753badb9e6655adb3f323739957b5a1/pandas_highcharts/display.py#L5)モジュールのコメントがヒントになります。</sup>

それに加え、pandas-highchartsにはHighchartのJSライブラリに渡すためのJSONを出力してくれる関数`pandas_highcharts.serialize()`もあります（パッケージの名前上、こちらがメインでしょうか）。JavaScriptでレンダリングするのが意図した用途であれば、この関数を使うために`import pandas_highcharts`するだけにとどめ、`from pandas_highcharts.display import display_charts`の行は削除して大丈夫です。

### Jupyterで表示する

Jupyterを[インストール](http://jupyter.org/install.html)し

```
pip3 install jupyter
```

起動:

```
jupyter notebook
```

するとブラウザが開くので、右上のNewをクリックしてPython 3を選び、コードを入力:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO
from pandas_highcharts.display import display_charts

# Data retrieved from http://www.quandl.com/api/v1/datasets/ODA/DEU_PCPIPCH.csv?column=1
data = """Date,Value\n2019-12-31,1.7\n2018-12-31,1.7\n2017-12-31,1.7\n2016-12-31,1.5\n2015-12-31,1.247"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), index_col=0, parse_dates=True)
df = df.sort_index()
display_charts(df, title="Germany inflation rate")
```

`>|`みたいなボタンを押すとチャートが表示されるはずです。

([pandas-highchartsのサンプルノートブック](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/gtnx/pandas-highcharts/blob/master/example.ipynb)から拝借したコードです。他にもいろいろなグラフの種類の例があります)

### Highchartライブラリで表示する

ウェブページを表示するための何らかのコードとHighchartライブラリをHTMLビュー側で利用できるようにセットアップして、

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO
import pandas_highcharts

    # HTMLビューを返すコード内

    data = """Date,Value\n2019-12-31,1.7\n2018-12-31,1.7\n2017-12-31,1.7\n2016-12-31,1.5\n2015-12-31,1.247"""
    df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), index_col=0, parse_dates=True)
    df = df.sort_index()
    chart = pandas_highcharts.serialize(df, render_to='my-chart', output_type='json')

    # どうやってビュー側に渡すかは利用しているウェブフレームワークに依存します。
    # 以下のコードはただの例:
    return render_template('chart', chart_json=chart)
```

HTMLビュー側:

```
<div id="my-chart"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  new Highcharts.Chart({{chart_json|safe}});
</script>
```

([READMEのサンプル](https://github.com/gtnx/pandas-highcharts#usage)を参考にしました)